# How to effectively remove a line in the middle of a large file?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Way to Delete a Line from Large File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329417/fastest-way-to-delete-a-line-from-large-file-in-python)
>   [How to edit a line in middle of txt file without overwriting everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868499/how-to-edit-a-line-in-middle-of-txt-file-without-overwriting-everything)

I know I can read every line into a list, remove a line, then write the list back.

But the file is large, is there a way to remove a part in the middle of the file, and needn't rewrite the whole file?

Comment: For clarity, are you talking about Py2 or Py3?

Comment: Added the specific tag to the question.

Comment: If you remove a part of a file, subsequent data needs to move or leave empty space. There's no way around it except maybe low-level filesystem access might be able to strip a single fixed-size (typically 4k) block.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868499/how-to-edit-a-line-in-middle-of-txt-file-without-overwriting-everything

Comment: And perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329417/fastest-way-to-delete-a-line-from-large-file-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if a way to change the file in place, even using low-level file system commands, but you don't need to load it into a list, so you can do this without a large memory footprint:

```
with open('input_file', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output_file', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if should_delete(line):
                pass
            else:
                output_file.write(line)
```

This assumes that the section you want to delete is a line in a text file, and that `should_delete` is a function which determines whether the line should be kept or deleted.  It is easy to change this slightly to work with a binary file instead, or to use a counter instead of a function.

**Edit:**  If you're dealing with a binary file, you know the exact position you want to remove, and its not too near the start of the file, you may be able to optimise it slightly with `io.IOBase.truncate` (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase).  However, I would only suggest pursuing this if the a profiler indicates that you really need to optimise to this extent.